# can't assign to function call if pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe with several columns. One of the columns is "category" consist of string which looks like:
`...:-U campus -u stevendu -l h_data=4G,h_rt=86400,h_vmem=4G -pe single 1:...`

In the category field, I need extract the `h_data` data, covert the value to gigabytes (see below for explanation) and make it a new column.
If the value of `h_data` ends with a `“G”` or `“g”`, the data is in the unit of “gigabytes”. If the value ends with `“m”` or `“M”`, the data is in the unit of megabytes. 
For example, if the category field has `h_data=2048M,h_rt=86400,exclusive=TRUE`, extract the 2048M, and convert it to 2048 / 1024 = 2 (gigabytes).

I did this by following way:

```
match = re.search('(h_data=(\d{1})([G|M]))', str(df.category))
if match.group(3) == 'G': # h_data in GB, no convertion
     df('h_data') = match.group(2)
elif match.group(3) == 'M': # h_data in MB, convert it to GB
    df('h_data') = str(float(match.group(2))/1024)
else:   # h_data in KB, convert it to GB
     df('h_data') = float(match.group(2))/1048576
```

But I got the `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call.`
Where is my error?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? Specifically, the part about how to access columns?

Comment: `x(whatever) = something_else` is invalid syntax in Python. So `df('h_data') = match.group(2)` is not valid, or your other two assignments

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use str.extract:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
  h_data
0   123G
1   456M
2    789

In [12]: res = df.h_data.str.extract('(\d+)([G|M]?)')

In [13]: res[0] = res[0].astype(int)

In [14]: res
Out[14]:
     0  1
0  123  G
1  456  M
2  789
```

Now you can use where to multiply the number appropriately:

```
In [15]: res[0].where(res[1] == 'G', (res[0] / 1024).where(res[1] == 'M', res[0] / 1048576))
Out[15]:
0    123.000000
1      0.445312
2      0.000752
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

Note: You could also use an apply here.

```
In [21]: def normalize(row):
    ...:     if row[1] == "G":
    ...:         return row[0]
    ...:     elif row[1] == "M":
    ...:         return row[0] / 1024.
    ...:     else:
    ...:         assert not row[1]
    ...:         return row[0] / 1048576.
    ...:

In [22]: res.apply(normalize, axis=1)
Out[22]:
0    123.000000
1      0.445312
2      0.000752
dtype: float64
```